# Child accessing variable of parent

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to have my child class named "turret" access the variables "leftArrow" and "rightArrow" from the parent class "Game" so that the turret can rotate. The code is compiling, but for some reason, it's not recognizing the change in value of the parent variables. Here's the parent class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Game extends MovieClip
    {

        // variables etc
        public var leftArrow, rightArrow;


        public function Game()
        {
            // add an event listener to spawn a new ship every frame
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
            addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyPressedDown);
            addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyPressedUp);

        }

        function keyPressedDown(event:KeyboardEvent) 
        {
            if (event.keyCode == 37) // left arrow
            {
                leftArrow = true;
            } 
            if (event.keyCode == 39) // right arrow
            {
                rightArrow = true;
            }
        }

        function keyPressedUp(event:KeyboardEvent) 
        {
            if (event.keyCode == 37) // left arrow
            {
                leftArrow = false;
            } 
            if (event.keyCode == 39) // right arrow
            {
                rightArrow = false;
            }
        }

        function loop(e:Event)
        {


            // only spawn a ship if there are less than 10 already on screen
            if (numChildren < 10)
            {
                // make a new instance of the Ship class
                var s = new Ship();

                // add the ship to the display list
                addChild(s);

                // position and rotate the ship
                s.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                s.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;

                s.rotation = Math.random() * 360;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the child class:

```
package  
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public class Turret extends MovieClip 
    {

        public function Turret() 
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        }



        function update(e:Event)
        {

            // make the turret move with key presses
            if (MovieClip(parent).leftArrow)
            {
                trace("Made it here");
                this.rotation += 5;
            }

            if (MovieClip(parent).rightArrow)
            {
                this.rotation += 5;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure something has focus (try `stage.focus = this` in your Game class constructor) and that your leftArrow & rightArrow vars are indeed reacting to the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be different from what you think. Keyboard events does not go to **any** display object, they go to the one recognized as interactive object under focus. While it is simpler with mouse, keyboard is kind of tricky. That's why it is a good move to subscribe stage for keyboard events, because stage is the root of **all** display tree and bubbling keyboard events will pass through it for sure:

```
        public function Game()
        {
            if (stage) onStage();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);
        }

        private function onStage(e:Event = null):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);

            // add an event listener to spawn a new ship every frame
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyPressedUp);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressedDown);

        }
```